# Printing range of numbers without using loop?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me how this code works ? It prints numbers from 0 to 100, but I cannot understand how.

```
print(*range(True,ord("e")))
```

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? Do you understand who print works with multiple arguments? Do you understand what argument unpacking with the `*` operator does?

Answer (score 2):

`ord` accepts a character and returns the ASCII code. In this case `"e"` returns 101. The `*range` is unpacking the iterable that range creates. Enabling you to print out the values from True (1) to 101 - 1.

I found this out by googling each piece of code individually. Type in "ord python" then another search was "star range python". These searches lead to information you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

```py
print(*range(True,ord("e")))
```

Firstly, `print()` means that we are displaying some information on the screen.

Secondly, the `*` indicates that there may be more than one object to be printed.

Now, think of the `True` as a 0. `True` does nothing. The `ord("e")` means where is `e` in the Unicode. It returns that number, which is 101. Now, `range(start, end)` means every value between the start value (0), and end value (1).

Comment: Why wouldn't someone just do print(*range(0,100))?

Comment: No idea. They must have their reasons but I seen none why